# Event Receiver redirect to Visual web part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers, visual-web-part

Here is my Event Receiver to redirected to my visual web part:

```
   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       properties.Cancel = true;
       properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
       properties.RedirectUrl = "/SitePages/test_aspx.aspx";

   }
```

Hi this is my visual web part:

```
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        SPUser currentUser = web.CurrentUser;
        SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Test_Doc_Lib"];
        //            CheckBoxList1 = new CheckBoxList();
        SPGroupCollection webGroups = currentUser.Groups;
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = webGroups;
        CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        SPUser currentUser = web.CurrentUser;
        SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Test_Doc_Lib"];

    //    SPListItem thisItem = properties.ListItem;
       // SPListItem employeeItem = docLib.GetItemById(ID);
        // Query the second list for the item
        SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
        myQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = \"ID\"/>" +
        "<Value Type = \"Text\">";

        // Get a collection of the second list items selected by the query and pick the first (0) value as it should only return one!
        SPListItemCollection secondlistItemCol = docLib.GetItems(myQuery);
        SPListItem secondItem = secondlistItemCol[0];

        SPGroupCollection webGroups = currentUser.Groups;
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = webGroups;
        CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

        //Break the role inheritance from List and remove any RoleAssignments
        secondItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
        while (secondItem.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
        {
            secondItem.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
        }

        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
           if (li.Selected)
           {
                // Give permissions to a specific group
                SPGroup group = web.Groups.GetByID(Convert.ToInt32(li.Value));
                SPPrincipal principalGroup = group;
                SPRoleAssignment roleassignment_group = new SPRoleAssignment(group);
                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = docLib.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(principalGroup);

                secondItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a visual web part i'm getting list of group of current user. The user selects the necessary groups and presses a button save. After that assigns the rights to documents according to selected groups. How do I get the selected groups to assign permissions to a document? And how do I assign the rights to the just created document? Please help me. If there are examples show please.

Answer (score 1):

New Event Receiver: 
`
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace ItemAdding.EventReceiver1
{
    /// 
    /// События элемента списка
    /// 
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

```
   private HttpContext _context;
   public EventReceiver1 ()
  {
   _context = HttpContext.Current;
  } 


   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       //Временно отключаем срабатывание обработчика
       EventFiringEnabled = false;
       //Получаем файл из HttpContext
       HttpPostedFile file = _context.Request.Files[0];
       Stream fileStream = file.InputStream;
       byte[] fileByte = new byte[file.ContentLength];
       fileStream.Read(fileByte, 0, file.ContentLength);
       //Загружаем файл в библиотеку документов
       SPFile fileUploded = properties.Web.Files.Add(properties.AfterUrl, fileByte);
       //Включаем обработчик обратно
       EventFiringEnabled = true;
       //Отменяем добавление файла, которое делал пользователь
       properties.Cancel = true;
       properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
       //Делаем редирект
       properties.RedirectUrl = properties.Web.Url + "/SitePages/test_aspx.aspx?ID=" + fileUploded.UniqueId;
   }

}
```

}
`
And new visual web form:

`try`
           `{
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                string itemID = Page.Request.Params["ID"];
                SPDocumentLibrary doclib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, "/Test_Doc_Lib"));`
       `SPListItem item = doclib.GetItemByUniqueId(new Guid(itemID));`
           `}`
         `catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
}`

But when creating a document, event handler throws an error in a string:
HttpPostedFile file = _context.Request.Files[0]; error: "In an instance of Object reference not set to an object." What could it be? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your looking for somthing like this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteCollection))
{  
     using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(siteName))  
     {    
         SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[libraryName];    
         //Get folder    
         SPListItem item = docLib.Folders[1];    
         if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)     
              item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);    
              SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(group);          
              SPRoleDefinition roleDefination = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];    
              roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefination);    
              item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);    
              item.Update();  
      }
}
```

taken from here:

http://sridharu.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/sharepoint-assigning-permission.html#!/2008/12/sharepoint-assigning-permission.html

also on checking permissions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx

and another tut

http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/06/11/managing-user-roles-and-permissions-through-sharepoint-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010/

hope this helps :)

Comment: But this code to assign rights to a folder, but I need to assign rights to just created the document. How do I do that?

Comment: i think this is more inline what your looking for: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Programmatically-assign-specific-permission-in-SharePoint-153.php  you can try this also, you need to get the document in the list (splist) find which document and assign its permission http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/4a1c3fb5-4798-4506-a0dc-7c683033423f